# How to improve the performance iterating over 130 items uploading them to aws s3

Tags: java, performance, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, java-stream

I have to iterate over 130 Data Transfer Objects, and each time will generate a json to be uploaded to aws S3.

With no improvements, it takes around **90 seconds** the complete the whole process. I tried using lamba and not using lamba, same results for both.

```
for(AbstractDTO dto: dtos) {
    try {
        processDTO(dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, dto);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception e) {
        failedToUploadDTOs.add(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ": " + dto.fileName() + ".json");
    }
}
```

```
dtos.stream().forEach(dto -> {
    try {
        processDTO(dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, dto);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception e) {
        failedToUploadDTOs.add(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ": " + dto.fileName() + ".json");
    }
});
```

After some investigation, I concluded that the method processDTO takes around **0.650ms** per item to run.

My first attempt was to use **parallel streams**, and the results were pretty good, taking around **15 seconds** to complete the whole process:

```
dtos.parallelStream().forEach(dto -> {
    try {
        processDTO(dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, dto);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception e) {
        failedToUploadDTOs.add(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ": " + dto.fileName() + ".json");
    }
});
```

But I still need to decrease that time.
I researched about improving parallel streams, and discovered the **ForkJoinPool** trick:

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(PARALLELISM_NUMBER);
forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
dtos.parallelStream().forEach(dto -> {
    try {
        processDTO(dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, dto);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception e) {
        failedToUploadDTOs.add(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ": " + dto.fileName() + ".json");
    }
})).get();
forkJoinPool.shutdown();
```

Unfortunately, the results were a bit confusing for me.

- When PARALLELISM_NUMBER is 8, it takes around **13 seconds** to complete the whole process. Not a big improve.
- When PARALLELISM_NUMBER is 16, it takes around **8 seconds** to complete the whole process.
- When PARALLELISM_NUMBER is 32, it takes around **5 seconds** to complete the whole process.

**All tests were done using postman requests, calling the controller method which will end-up iterating the 130 items**

I'm satisfied with 5 seconds, using 32 as PARALLELISM_NUMBER, but I'm worried about the consequences.

- Is it ok to keep 32?
- What is the ideal PARALLELISM_NUMBER?
- What do I have to keep in mind when deciding its value?

I'm running on a Mac 2.2GHZ I7

```
sysctl hw.physicalcpu hw.logicalcp
hw.physicalcpu: 4
hw.logicalcpu: 8
```

Here's what **processDTO** does:

```
private void processDTO(int dealerCode, int yearPeriod, int monthPeriod, AbstractDTO dto) throws FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception {
    String flatJson = JsonFlattener.flatten(new JSONObject(dto).toString());
    String jsonFileName = dto.fileName() + JSON_TYPE;;
    String jsonFilePath = buildFilePathNew(dto.endpoint(), dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, AWS_S3_JSON_ROOT_FOLDER);
    uploadFileToS3(jsonFilePath + jsonFileName, flatJson);
}
```

```
public void uploadFileToS3(String fileName, String fileContent) throws FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception {
    if (s3client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, fileName)) {
        throw new FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception(ErrorMessages.FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS_IN_S3.getMessage());
    }
    s3client.putObject(bucketName, fileName, fileContent);
}
```

Comment: Does `processDTO` perform both json generation and uploading to S3?

Comment: You have 4 cores; with hyperthreading that's 8 concurrent threads. That it's faster with 32 threads tells me one of 2 things is true: either your process is IO bound and you should research nonblocking IO techniques or you measurements are wrong. My money's on the second option as you don't explain how you made your measurements.

Comment: Following to @karthick question ... would make more sense to simply send a single upload (network?) request for all those objects instead of individual requests. Or if 130 is too many can you batch them?

Comment: @awesoon i edited the question, posting the processDTO method. Yes, it transforms the DTO into String Json and then uploads to s3. All this in about 0.650ms

Comment: And of that, what is the breakdown of runtimes between JSON creation, uniqueness checking and the actual upload? Also; why bother to create the JSON if you might not need it?

Comment: @ValentinRuano added the new benchmark, same result tho.

Comment: "_I tried using lamba and not using lamba, same results for both._"  - no surprise there.

Comment: You need to identify your bottleneck within the processDTO() method. I'm willing to bet money the upload is what's taking most of the time. Time it and see if that's the case; if so, consider uploading your objects in bulk. There is no need to parallelize processes that are inherently flawed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider just edited adding how i tested. The whole process I used postman timer, and I found the 0.650ms for the processDTO method with a simple System.out.println start/end.

Comment: Might I suggest reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics-async.html), if you are IO bound then you may find better throughput using a truly async pipleline. Although you are going to have to learn a **lot** about async programming for that to truly work.

Comment: "_simple System.out.println start/end_" - this is not how you benchmark Java.

Comment: @altskop the processDTO() takes about 0.650ms to run (generate json and upload to s3), but it's running 130 times. Its seems ok to me, but its not ok since the number of items (130). If i upload all files at once, I'll still have to iterate over them and create a file for each one of them, right? Does it sounds better?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not sure if I'm IO bound, since I'm only generating a json string from a dto class and uploading it so s3. Am I wrong?

Comment: @fsakiyama uploading to s3 is IO. You are actually performing two operations per `processDTO` - `doesObjectExist` and `putObject`. I did not find if s3 client supports batch uploading, but link provided by Boris with async aws operations seems promising.

Comment: @awesoon Hmm thanks, thought it was more like a network bound. I'm still confused about what should I do.

Comment: IO - input/output - network is the same as disk. If it works for you then just use 32 threads. I don't see a massive problem; you're not writing performance code and a if a hack works for you then go with it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, I think I understood the problem. Since you've mentioned about non blocking api in aws, i'll read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduce to **8 seconds** thanks to all your helpful advices and explanations.

Since the bottleneck was the upload to aws s3, and you mentioned a non-blocking API at aws, after some research, I found out that the class *TransferManager* contains a **non-blocking** upload.

[TransferManager class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

So instead of using ForkJoinPool to increase the number of threads, I kept the simple parallelStream:

```
        dtos.parallelStream().forEach(dto -> {
            try {
                processDTO(dealerCode, yearPeriod, monthPeriod, dto);
            } catch (FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception e) {
                failedToUploadDTOs.add(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ": " + dto.fileName() + ".json");
            }
        });
```

And the uploadToS3Method changed a bit, instead of using an *AmazonS3*, I used the *TransferManager*:

```
public Upload uploadAsyncFileToS3(String fileName, String fileContent) throws FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception {
        if (s3client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, fileName)) {
            throw new FileAlreadyExistsInS3Exception(ErrorMessages.FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS_IN_S3.getMessage());
        }
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes());
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(fileContent.getBytes().length);
        return transferManager.upload(bucketName, fileName, targetStream, metadata);
}
```

This way, when the upload is called, it doesn't wait for it to finish, letting another DTO to be processed. When all DTO are processed, I check their upload status to see possible errors (outside the first forEach)

Comment: Question - what now happens when `TransferManager` is yet to create a file on the server and the next file - with the same name - is processed? Presumably, bang! As I said above, it's not as simple as just making things asynchronous.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh, if in the middle of the upload of the file named A, TransferManager start to process another file with the same name? If that's the case, It'll not happen in my case since the files cannot have the same name. But even having diff names, do you think there might be still a problem?

Comment: If so, then why bother checking?

Comment: Ah, you mean the doesObjectExist? This is to avoid the user to overwrite the file at s3. Each file is unique in s3 (key: user, year and month), and cannot be overriden.

Comment: Well exactly - my point is that with parallelism, and especially with asynchronous upload, this check doesn't do my anymore. Furthermore, there is an `uploadFileList` method which may work better. And finally, you ignore the return value which means if the upload fails you won't know...

Comment: futhermore - the documentation for `TransferManager` states "_[w]hen possible, `TransferManager` attempts to use multiple threads to upload multiple parts of a single upload at once._"; i.e. your own threading may be intefereing with its...

Comment: The check still makes sense to me, because if the user uploaded a batch of files yesterday, and today he is trying to upload that same batch for some reason, it'll not allow. Without the check, the file will be overriden whenever a new upload happens.

Comment: Regarding uploadFileList, that makes sense, I just don't know how turn the strings into files. Maybe temp files? But there might be a problem with the directory path, because a file must have exactly the s3 path, I'm not sure how to work this out yet. And yes, you're right, I'll never know when a file fails to upload, didn't see that...

Comment: Honestly - if you're happy with the speed; just fix the error detection. I'm just being pernicerty. If you wanted, you could mount an in-memory file system to write the files to that to stage the upload - do that in parallel and then give the whole lot to the uploader - probably massive overkill...

Answer (score 4):

The `parallelism` parameters decides how many threads will be used by `ForkJoinPool`. That's why by default `parallelism` value is the available CPU core count:

```
Math.min(MAX_CAP, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

In your case the bottlneck should be checking that a file exists and uploading it to S3. The time here will depend on at least few factors: CPU, network card and driver, operating system, other. It seems that S3 network operation time is not CPU bound in your case as you are observing improvement by creating more simulations worker threads, perhaps the network request are enqueued by the operating system.

The right value for `parallelism` varies from one workload type to another. A CPU-bound workflow is better with the default `parallelism` equal to CPU cores due to the negative impact of context switching. A non CPU-bound workload like yours can be speed up with more worker threads assuming the workload won't block the CPU e.g. by [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

There is no one single ideal value for `parallelism` in `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: Well, in modern concurrent programming non CPU bound - well specifically IO bound - operations are dealt with using nonblocking IO. This has proven to provide much better throughput, and much better scalability, using few threads. The days of "just throw more threads at it" are over...

Comment: Only if you have a non-blocking IO. In OP's question `s3client.doesObjectExist()` or `s3client.putObject()` appears to be blocking if spawning more worker threads is helping.

Comment: There's a non blocking API for Amazon S3.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki thanks for the explanation, I guess you're right regarding the aws bottleneck. I'll have a look into aws api.